# getting a subset of data to qplot

Tags: mysql, sql, r, graph

I'm grabbing a rather large amount of data from  MySQL database. It's around 150mb.

[image]

I am then graphing some of the fields:

```
> qplot(myValues$average_submitted_chrg_amt, myValues$average_Medicare_payment_amt, data=myValues, color=nppes_provider_country,xlim=c(0,10000),ylim=c(0,4000),alpha=0.01)
```

Just to be cool I am including the graph:

[image]

I'd like to regraph this taking a random sampling of rows from the SQL QUERY.

**Is there a way to graph a subset of myValues?**

Comment: like this `qplot(average_submitted_chrg_amt, 
        average_Medicare_payment_amt, data=myValues[sample(nrow(myValues),  100), ], color=nppes_provider_country,
        xlim=c(0,10000),ylim=c(0,4000),alpha=0.01)`. This uses `sample` to samlpe `100` rows, without replacement, from your dataset. Remember to `set.seed` , so that the `sample` is reproducible

Comment: thats awesome please make that into an answer. also,. could you please explain the set.seed? what is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sample` to get what rows to include in your subset and use `[` to subset/extract these rows from your data.

This will sample 5 numbers from 1 to 10 without replacement

```
sample(10, 5)
#[1]  5  7  8  3 10
```

If we sample again, we will likely get a different sample

```
sample(10, 5)
#[1] 10  2  6  1  9
```

To make the sampling reproducible we can set a seed (see `?set.seed`)

```
set.seed(1) ; sample(10, 5)
# [1] 3 4 5 7 2
set.seed(1) ; sample(10, 5)
# [1] 3 4 5 7 2
```

Your plot - use example `mtcars` dataset. You use `sample` to sample the rows

```
library(ggplot2)

data(mtcars)

set.seed(1)
qplot(mpg, wt, data=mtcars[sample(nrow(mtcars), 20), ], geom="point")
```

`mtcars[sample(nrow(mtcars), 20), ]` samples twenty rows from the dataset

Answer (score 1):

If you want a random subset from a MySQL query, here are two approaches.  To get an approximate 10% sample do:

```
select t.*
from (<your query here>) t
where rand() < 0.1;
```

To get a random sample of exactly n rows, do:

```
select t.*
from (<your query here>) t
order by rand()
limit <n>;
```

The first method is faster.

Comment: is there an "r" solution?

Comment: @Yuck . . . No doubt there is, but the question is tagged "sql" and "mysql".

Comment: And there is an RMySQL package.

Comment: tags are used to describe the question, not necessarily a limitation to the scope of the solution